# Exclude files containing current date using AWS S3 sync

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

We have an AWS s3 sync command that sync's the data from current folder to S3.
Below folder structure:

```
[root@server2022 logs]# ls -ltr
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   0 Sep 23 13:41 Error-20220921.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   0 Sep 23 13:41 Error-20220922.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   0 Sep 23 13:41 Error-20220923.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   0 Sep 23 13:41 Info-20220922.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   0 Sep 23 13:41 Info-20220923.txt
```

We are trying to exclude current date (yyyymmdd format).

`aws s3 sync . s3://our-bucket-logs --exclude '*-$(date '+%Y%m%d')*'`

Means we are trying to exclude Error-20220923.txt and Info-20220923.txt files (today 20220923).

But none of above commands work and this is continuing to sync to the S3 bucket.

What are we doing wrong?

**Updates:**
I success to do that using double quotes
`aws s3 sync . s3://our-bucket-logs --exclude "*-$(date '+%Y%m%d')*"`

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html#use-of-exclude-and-include-filters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're telling the command that you want to exclude certain files, but then you're telling it you want to include everything.

You should get rid of the `--include` option, and you should use double quotes around the `--exclude` expression to make sure globbing works:

```
$ aws s3 sync . s3://our-bucket-logs --exclude "*-$(date '+%Y%m%d')"
```